# Is it necessary to create ASP.NET 4.0 SQL session state database, distinct from existing ASP.NET 2.0 ASPState DB?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, .net-4.0, session-state, asp.net-4.0

Is the **ASP.NET 4.0** SQL session state mechanism backward-compatible with the ASP.NET 2.0 schema for session state, or should/must we create a separate and distinct session state database for our ASP.NET 4.0 apps?

I'm leaning towards the latter anyway, but the 2.0 database *seems* to just work, though I'm wondering if there are any substantive differences between the ASPState database schema / procedures between the 2.0 and 4.0 versions of ASP.NET.  Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There was no quick answer on this from anybody, so I did some digging.  I generated an `ASPState` database using the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool from .NET 2.0, and then I did the same thing using the same tool but from .NET 4.0.  Then, I generated scripts from each of those resulting SQL Server databases and used a comparison tool to isolate the differences.

What I found is:  **The only material difference between the `ASPState` schema from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 versions is the `dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions` stored procedure.**  That's the stored procedure called periodically by a SQL Server Agent scheduled job also installed by the tool.

Consequently, it would seem that **the schema for ASPState 2.0 and ASPState 4.0 are perfectly compatible** and so it's not necessary, from a technical standpoint, to segregate ASP.NET 2.0 and ASP.NET 4.0 session state – but I'll likely do it anyway.

(This finding was a bit surprising, as ASPState changed a lot from .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0.)

Details for each version's changed stored proc:

#### .NET 2.0 ASPState DeleteExpiredSessions stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions
AS
    DECLARE @now datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE()

    DELETE [ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempSessions
    WHERE Expires < @now

    RETURN 0   
GO
```

#### .NET 4.0 ASPState DeleteExpiredSessions stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DeleteExpiredSessions
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW 
    DECLARE @now datetime
    SET @now = GETUTCDATE() 
    CREATE TABLE #tblExpiredSessions 
    ( 
        SessionID nvarchar(88) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    )
    INSERT #tblExpiredSessions (SessionID)
        SELECT SessionID
        FROM [ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
        WHERE Expires < @now
    IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE ExpiredSessionCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
        FOR SELECT SessionID FROM #tblExpiredSessions 
        DECLARE @SessionID nvarchar(88)
        OPEN ExpiredSessionCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM ExpiredSessionCursor INTO @SessionID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM [ASPState].dbo.ASPStateTempSessions WHERE
                    SessionID = @SessionID AND Expires < @now
                FETCH NEXT FROM ExpiredSessionCursor INTO @SessionID
            END
        CLOSE ExpiredSessionCursor
        DEALLOCATE ExpiredSessionCursor
    END 
    DROP TABLE #tblExpiredSessions
RETURN 0     
GO
```

As for why the above change was necessary, I found the following MSDN blog post:

- [Deadlock when storing Asp.net sessions in SQL server during peak load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webtopics/deadlock-when-storing-asp-net-sessions-in-sql-server-during-peak-load)

Excerpt, in reference to the older procedure:

> ...
> This would take the locks on all
> the expired records for deletion and
> these locks may be promoted to page
> locks. This can give rise to deadlocks
> with other ‘session state write
> statements’ when the number of records
> marked for deletion increases. By
> default this stored procedure is
> supposed **to run every minute.**
> ...

Consequently, the newer version of the stored proc may be advisable for ASP.NET 2.0 apps, too.

One more thing I learned from the blog post that I did not know:  ASP.NET 4.0 session state mechanism now offers **compression**.  Search on `compressionEnabled` at [sessionState Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100)).

---

Finally, I also just found something relevant from Microsoft, at [ASP.NET Side-by-Side Execution Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/a99txfy5(v=vs.140)).  Excerpt:

> ...
> If SQL Server is used to manage
> session state, all versions of ASP.NET
> (of the .NET Framework) that are
> installed on the same computer can
> share the SQL state server that is
> installed with the latest version of
> ASP.NET. **The schema for session state
> is the same in all versions of
> ASP.NET.**

(Though there are some differences in implementation not specific to the schema.)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! It helped us find a resolution. For anyone else with the issue here is a m$ KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973849